# Unity VR Game Build Hiccup,Unity VR Game Hiccup

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, build-error

So I'm creating a VR game for Google Cardboard utilising the 2022 version. I recently updated my Unity version and installed a package named GUI after downloading the Google Cardboard SDK. I've been attempting to build the game for Android, but it keeps giving me this error message about my AndroidManifest.xml script (I've tried developing for Desktop and it succeeded). Another terrifying thing it displays is a GUI script error from GUIUtility.cs. Every time I try to run this specific script to retrieve the error, a pop-up message stating "File not Found" appears. My Android SDK has been upgraded, and Visual Studio is my IDE. I'm not sure what the issue is.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzb0T.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av7x6.jpg)

We tried Asking ChatGPT and doind something YouTube Videos suggested but we're still at a dead ened. If anyone has any solution or has experienced this while building a Unity Game, please suggest ways we can solve these! Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem in version 2022 lts. The Cardboard application won't build and throw similar errors.
I solved it by switching to Unity version 2021 lts and changing the current SDK and JDK to SDK and JDK of Unity 2019 from "preference->External tools" and then updating the SDK. Try and see if this works.
[image: My external tools settings]